# ReplicateM Equivalent in F#

Tags: haskell, f#

Is there any equivalent function for `ReplicateM` (of `Haskell`) in `F#`?

Example :

```
replicateM 2 [1,2,3] = 
[[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find it in [F#+](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpPlus) and it's defined for both `List` and `Seq`:

```ml
#r @"c:\packages\FSharpPlus-1.0.0\lib\net45\FSharpPlus.dll"

open FSharpPlus

List.replicateM 2 [1;2;3]

// val it : List<int list> =
//  [[1; 1]; [1; 2]; [1; 3]; [2; 1]; [2; 2]; [2; 3]; [3; 1]; [3; 2]; [3; 3]]

Seq.replicateM 2 [1;2;3]
// val it : seq<int> list =
// [seq [1; 1]; seq [1; 2]; seq [1; 3]; seq [2; 1]; seq [2; 2]; seq [2; 3];
//   seq [3; 1]; seq [3; 2]; seq [3; 3]]
```

If you are translating from Haskell there is a Compatibility.Haskell module in [this project](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Compatibility) with that function and other Haskell bindings.

In fact the last argument can be a list or any other Applicative but if you don't want to use the library and you're happy with a version that works only with `list` you can define it like this:

```ml
let replicateM n x = 
    let k m m' = List.collect (fun x -> 
        List.collect(fun xs -> 
            [List.Cons(x,xs)]) m') m       
    List.foldBack k (List.replicate n x) [[]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The function is not available in standard libraries, so if you do not want to rely on external libraries, you'll need to write it yourself. The easiest implementation looks like this:

```
let rec replicateM m l = seq {
  if m = 1 then 
    // If we want just one replication, generate singleton lists
    for v in l do yield [v]
  else 
    // Otherwise, iterate over all lists with m-1 replicates
    for s in replicateM (m - 1) l do
      // .. and append elements from 'l' to the front
      for v in l do yield v::s }
```

Comment: The problem I have now is to use the find operator on the Sequence I get using replicateM.

But it seems that find(==m) is not defined on the Sequences.. Is there any other implementation of replicateM in F# that returns the List.

Comment: Got it working

 let replicateM' (n:int) source =   Seq.toList (replicateM n source)